# One-to-many relationship: how to set default entity-value?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a one-to-many relationship `Cart-SendingMethod`. I would like to set a default `SendingMethod` for new `Carts`. So I have tried this:

```
<?php
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MetodoEnvio", inversedBy="metodoEnvios")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="metodo_envio_id", referencedColumnName="id")
**/
private $metodoEnvio = 1;
```

but doesn't work... I get:

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a integer variable ("1") when I call Cart.SendingMethod.id from a view file
```

So how to set a default `SendingMethod` for new `Products`?

I could do it in the controller, but I would like to know if it is possible from the entity `Product`.

Note: I didn't know exactly if this is a symfony or doctrine question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to introduce dependencies into your entity.

The obvious and cleaner way to do it would be to create a CartFactory service, and inject that into any controller (or other class) that needs to create carts.  Inject your EntityManager and other dependencies into the factory.  That way you DRY up your cart-initialization code, and avoid bulking up your controller.

Comment: Or just add a create method to CartRepository and not fool around with a Factory specific class.

Comment: @Cerad - That can work too, though if you have dependencies beyond the EM for configuring the Cart, it might start to get blurry.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the property's default value inside the constructor like this:

```
public function __construct(..)
{
   $this->property = new OtherObject();
}
```

Comment: thanks. Anyway I would have to instantiate an `OtherObject` in the controller and pass it as an argument, wouldn't it? Or could I do it inside constructor? I want to use a `OtherObject` already saved in the database.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I suspect the poster wants to link to an existing persisted entity.  Just a guess.

Comment: I'd suggest using a controller for now.  Fragile but simple.  To make it transparent (like @nifr shows) you will have to use an onFlush (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush) listener and add some additional code.